# Rails resources route with dynamic prefix instead of controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a TextsController, each Text can be of a different (fixed) type.

Let's say I have a "book" type. I want to create a resource route to show a text, and I want the route to look like this:

`/book/my-book`

Another type, "manual" for instance, should lead to using the following URL:

`/manual/rtfm`

Well, I [have](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) [RTFM](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-scope) and I can't get it to work the way I thought it should work.

Here's what I've tried:

```
scope '/:text_type' do
  resources :texts, only: :show
end
```

`rake routes` shows me the following route spec:

`text GET /:text_type/texts/:id(.:format) texts#show`

I don't get why the static 'texts' segment should be there?

So I tried including an empty `path` option:

```
scope '/:text_type', path: '' do
  resources :texts, only: :show
end
```

Which doesn't change anything, I guess because ([from source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1d94fa0de3fdc8d2dbc60aacdd168a4f2dea146e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L730)) my first argument to `scope` actually overrides any value given to `path`.
The only route setup that got me what I'm looking for is this:

```
scope '/:text_type' do
  resources :texts, only: :show, path: ''
end
```

It seems to completely defeat the purpose of `scope` which is to "[scope] a set of routes to the given default options".

Why wouldn't any of the previous forms actually override `path` for my `resources` call?

Looks like a bug to me?

So should I file a bug report, or will you hit me hard on the head with the f* manual? ^^

Answer (score 1):

First of all the scoping thing. Routes with scope are for namespacing routes, as you would do for admin areas. So the mentioned routes are generated correctly and there is no bug (and no bug report needed). You can read more details about namespacing at [Controller Namespaces and Routing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast).
You could slug the parameters yourself by following '[Creating Vanity URLs in Rails](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)'
or use the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem like the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) advises.
Though I would stick to ids as long as I could for several reasons.

Comment: Well, the text type path prefix is actually purely a semantic thing for SEO, there's no implementation difference between types of texts internally.
According to the documentation *and* the link you gave, scope is a mean to apply default attributes to a set of routes. They use it in the examples for namespacing to, in fact, work around the effect of `namespace` that will route to controllers nested inside modules.
I can achieve what I want without `scope`, but I'd have to repeat my path option on each and every route, a duplication `scope` is supposedly here to avoid...

Comment: O.K. The I ask the question a different way: What do you expect a path like /book/my-book or /manual/rtfm to return (I assume they are GET routes)?

Comment: Hmm I want to show the Text that is identified by the "my-book" or "rtfm" slug/id.

Comment: Is that slug/id (e.g. "my-book", "rtfm") unique in specific scope?

Comment: I changed the answer concerning the changed question.